# Baby Rudin Exersise 6.3(a)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I'm trying to prove $(a)$. Here is what I have done:

Suppose $f$ is integrable and set $\alpha=\beta_1$. Then there is a partition $P=\{x_0=-1,x_1,\dots,x_n=1\}$ of $[-1,1]$ such that $$U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)\le \epsilon$$ for any $\epsilon >0$. WLOG assume $0=x_k$ is a point of $P$ (if not, consider an appropriate refinement; the corresponding difference will still be less than or equal to $\epsilon$). If so, then $$U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)=M_k-m_k$$ where $M_k$ and $m_k$ are sup and inf (resp.) of $f$ in $[x_{k-1},x_k]$. Let $\delta=x_{k+1}$ and $x\in (0,\delta)$. Consider 3 cases:

1. If $f(0)=f(x)$, then $|f(0)-f(x)|=0\le \epsilon$,
2. If $f(0)>f(x)$, then $|f(0)-f(x)|=f(0)-f(x)\le M_k-m_k$ (since $f(0)\le M_k$ and $f(x)\ge m_k$ on $[x_{k-1},x_k]$),
3. If $f(x)>f(0)$, then $|f(0)-f(x)|=f(x)-f(0)\le M_k-m_k$ (since $f(x)\le M_k$ and $f(0)\ge m_k$on $[x_{k-1},x_k]$).

Thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}f(x)=f(0)$.

Conversely, assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}f(x)=f(0)$. Then given $\epsilon$ there is $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|< \epsilon$ whenever $x\in (0, \delta)$. Let $P=\{-1=x_0,0=x_1,\delta/2=x_2, 1=x_3\}$ be a partition of $[-1,1]$. Enough to show $U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha) < c \epsilon$ for some constant $c$. We have $U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)=M_2-m_2$ (with the above notation).

If $f$ was continuous on $[0,\delta/2]$, it would attain its maximum and minimum on that interval, and we could write $$U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)=(M_2-f(0))+(f(0)-m_2)=(f(\xi_2)-f(0))-(f(0)-f(\psi_2))< 2\epsilon$$ (where $\xi_2,\psi_2\in [0,\delta/2]$). But it is not the case.

- How do I show $U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha) < c \epsilon$ to conclude the proof of this part?
- How do I show that the value of the integral is $f(0)$?
- Is my proof of the first part correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the deinitions of $\sup$ and $\inf$, there are $\xi_1,\xi_2\in[0,\delta/2]$ such that $$M_2-\epsilon< f(\xi_1) \text{ and } m_2+\epsilon > f(\xi_2),$$ whence \begin{multline}|M_2-m_2|< f(\xi_1)-f(\xi_2)+2\epsilon \le|f(\xi_1)-f(\xi_2)|+2\epsilon   \\     \le|f(\xi_1)-f(0)|+|f(\xi_2)-f(0)|+2\epsilon \le\epsilon+\epsilon+2\epsilon=4\epsilon.\end{multline}

That the value of the integral (provided $f$ is integrable) is equal to $f(0)$ follows from the fact that $$L(P,f,\alpha)\le \underline {\int}_{-1}^1fd\alpha\le   f(0)\le \overline{\int}_{-1}^1 fd\alpha \le U(P,f,\alpha).$$

The first part of your proof looks fine to me.